# Redirect of some API requests from one Web App to another

Tags: azure, iis, azure-web-app-service

I have two Azure Web App. I want to configure a redirect of some API requests from one Web App to another. All requests that come to /api/v1/resources should go to the webapp2, all other requests that come to example /api on webapp1 will remain on the web app webapp1.

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="[RULE NAME]" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="https://webapp1.test.net/api/v1/resources" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://webapp2.test.net/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
          </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

But my redirect does not work.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules FRT will tell you what exactly is `{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer:

In web.config I added

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="Rewrite">
            <match url="^api/v1/resources/?(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="https://webapp2.test.net/api/v1/resources/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
```

and add file applicationHost.xdt

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
 <system.webServer>
 <proxy xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" enabled="true" preserveHostHeader="false" reverseRewriteHostInResponseHeaders="false" />
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>

This file will override applicationhost.config, taking advantage of a feature in Azure, called Azure Site Extensions, that provides a mechanism to apply transforms to applicationhost.config using XDT transforms.
```

Answer (score 0):

Its just because {HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI} does not contain https://.

[image]

So please try either {CACHE_URL} with 443 port

```
<rule name="rulename" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="https://webapp1.test.net:443/api/v1/resources" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://webapp2.test.net/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
          </rule>
```

or {MATCH All} with{https}=^on$

```
 <rule name="123" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="webapp1.test.net/api/v1/resources" />
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^on$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://webapp2.test.net/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
          </rule>
```